# String does not name a type

Tags: esp32

I'm using Arduino IDE for ESP32 WROOM board. I am testing the OTA feature with the ESP32httpUpdate library. I am using the example sketch of the library with the name httpUpdate.ino
However, as soon as I change the update url with a string pointer that I declare globally, it is throwing a compile error that String does not name a type. Any ideas?

```
/**
 * httpUpdate.ino
 *
 *  Created on: 27.11.2015
 *
 */
String* FIRMWARE_UPDATE_VERSION = "1000";

String* updateURL = "XYZ.php";

#include <Arduino.h>

#include <WiFi.h>

#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP32httpUpdate.h>

#define USE_SERIAL Serial

void setup() {

    USE_SERIAL.begin(115200);
    // USE_SERIAL.setDebugOutput(true);

    USE_SERIAL.println();
    USE_SERIAL.println();
    USE_SERIAL.println();

    for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
        USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
        USE_SERIAL.flush();
        delay(1000);
    }

    WiFi.begin("SSID", "PASSWORD");

}

void loop() {
    // wait for WiFi connection
    Serial.println("Yolo");
    if((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) {

        t_httpUpdate_return ret = ESPhttpUpdate.update(updateURL, FIRMWARE_UPDATE_VERSION);

        switch(ret) {
            case HTTP_UPDATE_FAILED:
                USE_SERIAL.printf("HTTP_UPDATE_FAILD Error (%d): %s", ESPhttpUpdate.getLastError(), ESPhttpUpdate.getLastErrorString().c_str());
                break;

            case HTTP_UPDATE_NO_UPDATES:
                USE_SERIAL.println("HTTP_UPDATE_NO_UPDATES");
                break;

            case HTTP_UPDATE_OK:
                USE_SERIAL.println("HTTP_UPDATE_OK");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G28416DlDBxZEHrLdYylUgBE80ePzbWDJtMKpQ6lJKk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: link to the code

Comment: Code, that is this short, should be copied directly into the question and formatted correctly as code by selecting it and pressing the `{}` button in the editor. I've done this for you now, but please remind it for the next question.

Comment: Hey thanks. I did try to add the code in the question itself but it got weird and I couldn't do the formatting clearly so I gave a link.

Comment: what is `String* updateURL = "XYZ.php";`? you assign a pointer to constant char array to a pointer to String object. Where did you see something like this? It should be `const char* updateURL = "XYZ.php";` or `String updateURL = "XYZ.php";`

Comment: I initially started with String updateURL = "XYZ.php" but the same error came up. Then I saw in the http library that the httpUpdate function accepts a pointer value so I was trying out with a string pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String` is included by Arduino.h. Before `#include <Arduino.h>` `String` is not defined. Move `#include <Arduino.h>` to the top of the file or remove it. If you remove it, the Arduino builder adds it.

Comment: Thank you. It worked!/